# ReferenceError: Galleria is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla2.5

I'm actually in the midst of moving Joomla 1.5 to 2.5. Yes I know I'm a bit late.

I've successfully upgraded from 1.5 to 2.5 Layout wise is fine and intact. However, previously, we have a galleria banner slideshow. After the upgrade, I've been receiving errors, ReferenceError: Galleria is not defined

It pointed out the following script is causing the problem. I believe it has the issues with Mootools but I've already installed a plugin to resolve the conflict.

```
<script>
jQuery.Galleria.loadTheme('http://locahost:8080/website/jupgrade/templates/template_main/js/galleria.classic.min.js');

jQuery.Galleria.run('#slideshow');
</script>
```

This is my first time doing Joomla upgrade.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think your problem is with Mootools.

Comment: Did you install the component that was creating the galleria slideshow? Where did you find this script? Is it hard coded in to your template?

Comment: Hi Sergio and Brent, Galleria slideshow is hard coded to the template since the website is maintained by me and not client. I was told to use jQuery instead of $ but I don't think I can put jQuery all for the source file from the framework downloaded. Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issues. I'm able to load the banners just that I need to fix the css to suit to my needs. Thank you.